# Not able to figure out getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print a text in html page through js .
My code is

```
var nameOfCreator = "XYZ";
var scriptcode="document.getElementById('billto_first_name').value='ABC' ";
frmB.Browser0422f79dce36f4c.evaluateJavaScript(scriptcode);
frmB.Browser0422f79dce36f4c.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('billto_first_name').value= nameOfCreator ");`
```

The expected output is XYZ but getting ABC.Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're setting the value to 'ABC' thats why

Comment: In the last line of the code I am trying overwriting "billto_first_name" with value in object nameOfCreator so that it shows XYZ as output but unable to show the value in object .

Comment: When you remove the 2nd and 3rd lines, what do you get ?

Comment: I guess the context in which you call `evaluateJavascript` (the `frmB...` stuff) is not the context where `nameOfCreator` exists, probably triggering some silent `ReferenceError`. What if you do `frmB.Browser0422f79dce36f4c.nameOfCreator = 'XYZ'`, is it still not overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
frmB.Browser0422f79dce36f4c.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('billto_first_name').value= '" + nameOfCreator + "'");
```

Comment: Glad it can help. I just continue what @StockOverflaw pointed out about `different context`.
regards